# Errors when switching from an ungrouped-data state to grouped or vice-versa in syncfusion's Schedule (react)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, schedule, syncfusion

We are using the ScheduleComponent (the react wrapper) and we need to toggle between a grouping-data state to an ungroupped-data state.

Here is how the markup looks like:

```
<ScheduleComponent
  width="100%"
  height="calc(100% - 60px)"
  currentView="TimelineWeek"
  selectedDate={state.selectedDate}
  eventSettings={state.eventSettings}
  group={state.group}
>
  <ViewsDirective>
    <ViewDirective option="TimelineDay" />
    <ViewDirective option="TimelineWeek" />
    <ViewDirective option="TimelineMonth" />
  </ViewsDirective>
  <Inject services={[TimelineViews, TimelineMonth]} />
  {resourcesDirective && resourcesDirective.length ? (
    <ResourcesDirective>
      {resourcesDirective.map(rd => (
        <ResourceDirective
          key={rd.field}
          field={rd.field}
          title={rd.title}
          name={rd.name}
          dataSource={rd.dataSource}
          textField={rd.textField}
          idField={rd.idField}
          colorField={rd.colorField}
        />
      ))}
    </ResourcesDirective>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
</ScheduleComponent>;
```

Here is a preview of the dynamically generated ScheduleComponent properties/parameters set passed to the ScheduleComponent for :

1- the ungrouped data state :

```
{
    "selectedDate": "2020-02-12T23:00:00.000Z",
    "eventSettings": {
        "fields": {
            "id": "id",
            "subject": {
                "name": "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae"
            },
            "startTime": {
                "name": "c8f10b79-a557-4e28-bb91-bc3f6428bfe0"
            },
            "endTime": {
                "name": "72cd7bde-a6d4-4877-a5c5-9d3e947a39d9"
            }
        },
        "dataSource": [{
            "id": "2f9a08d1-58aa-11ea-9e9a-0b771aade197",
            "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae": "task044",
            "b65757c2-d4c1-404c-8e42-f9377bfc18fc": "91ef822c-3d7e-4071-805a-3613aa2b4f87",
            "978c8dfc-ee35-48d4-9e60-41691c367ced": "{\"startDate\":\"2020-02-13T23:00:00.000Z\",\"endDate\":\"2020-02-13T23:00:00.000Z\"}",
            "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc": "id-ew9j",
            "38e1b256-aeb8-4fd7-a4db-337c1dda0605": 44,
            "372a6ad4-4f97-43a6-90f5-d5494241ba03": null,
            "c8f10b79-a557-4e28-bb91-bc3f6428bfe0": "2020-02-12T23:00:00.000Z",
            "72cd7bde-a6d4-4877-a5c5-9d3e947a39d9": "2020-03-17T23:00:00.000Z"
        }, {
            "id": "7b689441-57e5-11ea-b2fd-1568322e886b",
            "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae": "tassk03",
            "b65757c2-d4c1-404c-8e42-f9377bfc18fc": "ebda8884-cbc5-4030-a54d-34a2df32b701",
            "978c8dfc-ee35-48d4-9e60-41691c367ced": null,
            "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc": "id-aoab",
            "38e1b256-aeb8-4fd7-a4db-337c1dda0605": 95,
            "372a6ad4-4f97-43a6-90f5-d5494241ba03": null,
            "c8f10b79-a557-4e28-bb91-bc3f6428bfe0": "2020-02-25T23:00:00.000Z",
            "72cd7bde-a6d4-4877-a5c5-9d3e947a39d9": "2020-06-18T23:00:00.000Z"
        },
        ...]
    }
}
```

2- the grouped data state :

```
{
    "selectedDate": "2020-02-12T23:00:00.000Z",
    "eventSettings": {
        "fields": {
            "id": "id",
            "subject": {
                "name": "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae"
            },
            "startTime": {
                "name": "c8f10b79-a557-4e28-bb91-bc3f6428bfe0"
            },
            "endTime": {
                "name": "72cd7bde-a6d4-4877-a5c5-9d3e947a39d9"
            },
            "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc": {
                "name": "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc"
            }
        },
        "dataSource": [{
            "id": "2f9a08d1-58aa-11ea-9e9a-0b771aade197",
            "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae": "task044",
            "b65757c2-d4c1-404c-8e42-f9377bfc18fc": "91ef822c-3d7e-4071-805a-3613aa2b4f87",
            "978c8dfc-ee35-48d4-9e60-41691c367ced": "{\"startDate\":\"2020-02-13T23:00:00.000Z\",\"endDate\":\"2020-02-13T23:00:00.000Z\"}",
            "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc": "id-ew9j",
            "38e1b256-aeb8-4fd7-a4db-337c1dda0605": 44,
            "372a6ad4-4f97-43a6-90f5-d5494241ba03": null,
            "c8f10b79-a557-4e28-bb91-bc3f6428bfe0": "2020-02-12T23:00:00.000Z",
            "72cd7bde-a6d4-4877-a5c5-9d3e947a39d9": "2020-03-17T23:00:00.000Z"
        }, {
            "id": "7b689441-57e5-11ea-b2fd-1568322e886b",
            "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae": "tassk03",
            "b65757c2-d4c1-404c-8e42-f9377bfc18fc": "ebda8884-cbc5-4030-a54d-34a2df32b701",
            "978c8dfc-ee35-48d4-9e60-41691c367ced": null,
            "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc": "id-aoab",
            "38e1b256-aeb8-4fd7-a4db-337c1dda0605": 95,
            "372a6ad4-4f97-43a6-90f5-d5494241ba03": null,
            "c8f10b79-a557-4e28-bb91-bc3f6428bfe0": "2020-02-25T23:00:00.000Z",
            "72cd7bde-a6d4-4877-a5c5-9d3e947a39d9": "2020-06-18T23:00:00.000Z"
        },...]
    },
    "group": {
        "resources": ["92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc"]
    },
    "ResourcesDirective": [{
        "field": "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc",
        "title": "Tag-field",
        "name": "92b16d99-21fe-402c-ba3b-61d4fb5d9dfc",
        "dataSource": [{
            "content": "option1",
            "cellClass": "color1",
            "rippleColor": "#72C045",
            "id": "id-keho",
            "tagIndex": 0
        }, {
            "content": "option2",
            "cellClass": "color2",
            "rippleColor": "#F1921F",
            "id": "id-ew9j",
            "tagIndex": 1
        }, {
            "content": "option3",
            "cellClass": "color3",
            "rippleColor": "#F16651",
            "id": "id-aoab",
            "tagIndex": 2
        }],
        "textField": "content",
        "idField": "id",
        "colorField": "rippleColor"
    }]
}
```

When switching from an ungrouped schedule state to the grouped , by calling the setState method as the following:

```
this.setState({
      selectedDate: newProps.selectedDate,
      eventSettings: newProps.eventSettings,
      group: newProps.group,
      ResourcesDirective: newProps.ResourcesDirective,
    });
```

we get these errors :

> ej2-schedule.umd.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateResourceLevels' of null

And when switching from the grouped-data state to the ungrouped we get those errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

When it's the initial display, everything works fine for the same parameters set for either the grouped or ungrouped states, problems occur only when switching from an ungrouped to grouped states or vice-versa. Switching from a grouped state to another (by grouping based on another resource) also works fine.
we are using

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"webpack": "^4.12.0"
```

**EDIT AFTER Balasubramanian's answer**

Here are two stackblitz reproducing the mentionned errors :
1- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-cerwzz : it happens when clicking on the **"Ungroup"** button : the error is visible in the console.

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

2- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-cz2nhg : when clicking on the **"group"** button we can see:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateResourceLevels' of null

**EDIT2 AFTER Balasubramanian's second answer**

Now it's going much better as we can group / ungroup ([screenshot here](https://i.imgur.com/1PhLsyO.gifv)) but we still have another issue that i couldn't reproduce : when the schedule starts ungrouped initially and then we group it we get this error :

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '__eventList' in null
>     at Function.e.addOrGetEventData (ej2-base.umd.min.js:10)
>     at Function.e.remove (ej2-base.umd.min.js:10)
>     at i.unwireEvents (ej2-schedule.umd.min.js:10)
>     at i.destroy (ej2-schedule.umd.min.js:10)
>     at t.n.destroy (ej2-schedule.umd.min.js:10)
>     at t.n.componentWillUnmount (ej2-react-base.umd.min.js:10)
>     at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (react-dom.development.js:21896)
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
>     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
>     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
> ```

I tried to find any difference with your latested demo for ungroupping, i only found that you keep **ResourcesDirective** always included inside the **ScheduleComponent** whether there is grouping is active or not and it's not possible for us to guess and pass any **ResourcesDirective** when the grouping is not active as we don't know which possible ressources for grouping will be selected by the user later on so i tried to make it generated dynamically only for the grouping case in order to try reproduce the error we got in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-dudcnr) but it's the same error we got before that i saw and not the new one :

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateResourceLevels' of null
>     at i.generateColumnLevels (util.js:5)
>     at i.renderLayout (util.js:5)
>     at e.initializeLayout (util.js:5)
>     at e.render (util.js:5)
>     at t.n.initializeView (util.js:5)
>     at eval (util.js:5)
>     at e.notify (dom.js:275)
>     at t.n.trigger (util.js:6)
>     at eval (util.js:5)
>     at e.notify (dom.js:275)
> ```
>
> we don't get this old error anymore in our app.

Answer (score 1):

We have validated your shared code snippets and prepared a sample based on that. In below sample, the data source of the resources and group for the scheduler has been declared in the setstate value and the sample can be viewed from the following link.

**Code snippet:**

```
export class Timescale extends SampleBase {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    // this.data = extend([], dataSource.scheduleData.concat(dataSource.timelineData), null, true);
    this.state = {
      resourceDataSource: [],
      grp: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let resourceDataSource = [
      { AirlineName: 'Airways 1', AirlineId: 1, AirlineColor: '#EA7A57' },
      { AirlineName: 'Airways 2', AirlineId: 2, AirlineColor: '#357cd2' },
      { AirlineName: 'Airways 3', AirlineId: 3, AirlineColor: '#7fa900' }
    ];
    let grp = ['Airlines'];
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      that.setState({
        resourceDataSource
      });
    }, 2000)
    setTimeout(() => {
      that.setState({
        grp
      });
    }, 2000)
  }
  render() {
    const { resourceDataSource } = this.state;
    const { grp } = this.state;
    return (<div className='schedule-control-section'>
      <div className='col-lg-9 control-section'>
        <div className='control-wrapper'>
          <ScheduleComponent delayUpdate='true' height='650px' ref={schedule => this.scheduleObj = schedule} selectedDate={new Date(2019, 0, 10)} group={{ resources: grp }} timeScale={{ enable: false }}>
            <ResourcesDirective>
              <ResourceDirective field='AirlineId' title='Airline Name' name='Airlines' allowMultiple={true}
                dataSource={resourceDataSource} textField='AirlineName' idField='AirlineId' colorField='AirlineColor'>
              </ResourceDirective>
            </ResourcesDirective>
            <ViewsDirective>
              <ViewDirective option='Day' />
              <ViewDirective option='Week' />
              <ViewDirective option='WorkWeek' />
              <ViewDirective option='Month' />
            </ViewsDirective>
            <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Resize, DragAndDrop]} />
          </ScheduleComponent>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-eqrtwk?file=index.js

Comment: hey , thanks , i updated my question and i put two stackblitz reproducing the errors

Answer (score 1):

The group property is dependent to the resources property. So we can’t able to change the state for both properties. By setting the state value for group property is enough for achieving your requirements.

Don't do it like this:

```
group={isGrouped ? { resources: grp } : undefined}
```

Do it like this:

```
group={{ resources: isGrouped ? grp : [] }}
```

Sample1: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-rfxh7s?file=index.js

Sample2: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw8qs1-jcm3c1?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer but we're still having an issue while grouping, i've updated my question again

Answer (score 0):

The ‘Group’ property is interrelated to the ‘Resources’ property. So if we change the state for ‘Group’ it will be rendered based on the ‘Resources’. So the Resources should be initialized as our previously shared sample. While changing the state, the Group will be changed first and then the resources, at the time of changing Group state the resources become null, in the case, the reported error(TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateResourceLevels' of null) will occur. So we suggest you add the Resources directive at initial loading and do perform the state changes for Group property alone to overcome the reported problem.

Comment: any clue about the "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '__eventList'" error ? , i'm not having the "Cannot read property 'generateResourceLevels' of null) " anymore for now but that one i just mentioned and unfortunatelly i couldn't reproduce it in the stackblitz